# Delete text style in input text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend

Hey how i can change input text style to delete style?

```
<input type="text" value=">Hello World!" />
```

i want change my input text style like this
<del>Hello World!</del>

Comment: does this answer your Question if you search you can find it before ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply inline css

```
<input style="text-decoration:line-through;" type="text" value=">Hello World!" />
```